# Remove file path and extension, and just leaving the file name

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file path `/home/test/domain/example.txt`
It can also be completely different in length and file extension. For example:

```
/reallylongpath/example/longername.vb
```

I need to remove the extension name '.' and after, and I need to delete everything other than the file name. The two examples above I would need `example` and `longername`.

I was assuming to go to the last occurrence of '/' but not sure.

I am looking to do this using bash.

Comment: [Bashguide: Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: It would be easier in `zsh` (and even csh/tcsh where the feature comes from though you wouldn't want to use those these days): `$file:t:r` (*root name* of the *tail* of the file). That's also available in `vim`. `bash` has it for *history substitution* (like `echo !:$:t:r` for the root of tail of last word in previous command line) but not parameter expansion unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get only filename using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44735/how-to-get-only-filename-using-sed)

Answer (score 5):

For a fixed extension, the `basename` utility could be used to do this:

```
$ f=/home/test/domain/example.txt
$ basename -- "$f" .txt
example
```

But since you have arbitrary extensions, you need to explicitly pick the last extension to pass to `basename`. The shell's parameter expansions can be used here:

```
$ basename -- "$f" ".${f##*.}"
example
```

Or, while we're at it, use parameter expansions for both removals.

```
$ x="${f##*/}"; x="${x%.*}"; echo "$x"
example
```

`${var##pattern}` takes `var` with the longest prefix matching `pattern` removed. With `%%` it takes the suffix instead, and with one `#` or `%` the shortest prefix or suffix.

If you consider something like `.txt.gz` a single expansion to be removed, you could use `x="${x%%.*}"` (with a double `%%`) instead.

Note that the last solution will give an empty string as output, if the given path ends in a `/`, while `basename` would ignore trailing slashes. The other case that needs care is where the directory names can also contain dots, so something like `/home/test/domain.orig/example.txt.gz`, or where the filename contains no dots at all. (I didn't double check all those cases.)

For discussion on related issues, see:

- [dirname and basename vs parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253524/dirname-and-basename-vs-parameter-expansion)
- [shellcheck is advising not to use basename: why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94295/shellcheck-is-advising-not-to-use-basename-why)

Answer (score 0):

```
basename /reallylongpath/example/longername.vb |cut -d"." -f1
```

EDIT: this will fail in case of '.' in the filename. However

```
basename /reallylongpath/example/lo.ngername.vb |rev| cut -d"." -f2- |rev
```

will provide you with the correct

```
lo.ngername
```